# How to write a sql to get certain column of data with certain substring or starting characters

Tags: sql, database

My question is: is there any in-build standard sql function to make such task easier?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be but depend on DBMS, Which one is yours ? And you can google for `LIKE` operator for your problem.

Comment: for sql server we have substring, left, right, reverse, replace, stuff any many more functions. similarly every database has their own set of functions

Comment: Anything with oracle pedigree... perhapes? I am using java derby for my testing run. The 'like' keyword would filter out all the string with single character match?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports the LIKE operator and the `%` wildcard.  (Also the `_` wildcard.)  To find all rows that begin with "abc" you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable Where MyColumn LIKE 'abc%'
```

To find all rows that contain the substring "abc" somewhere within MyColumn, you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable Where MyColumn LIKE '%abc%'
```

Check out [this helpful page](http://www.mandsconsulting.com/sql-like-oracle-like-operator-sql-syntax-examples).